# Webdeploy from commandline not taking app offline even with -enableRule:AppOffline

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, web-deployment, webdeploy

When I try to run this command from commandline to deploy asp.net core website:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\IIS\\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe" -allowUntrusted -verb:sync -sourc
e:contentPath="%USERPROFILE%\ProjectFolder\bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\publish" -dest:contentPath="sitename",ComputerNa
me="https://siteurl.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=sitename",UserName='myusername',Password='mypassword',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -retryAttempts:20
```

Get this error:

```
Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
```

When I stop website on web server, then deployment succeeds:

I was expecting `-enableRule:AppOffline` should force website offline. But it still keeps the lock on website dll.

How we can force webdeploy to overwrite files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you see on the site if the App_Offline.htm is being created? If yes, try renaming to app_offline.htm (all lower case). Does that shutdowns the site? There is bug in AspNetCoreModule for App_Offline.htm file being case-sensitive, see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/50).

Comment: Are you aware of any workaround for this other than manually stopping the website or manually renaming App_Offline.html to app_offline.html. More of a automatic workaround :)

Comment: I assume it's you working on the temp solution with dev team on the github? If not, see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/50 for suggested workaround until the bug is fixed.

Comment: yup, it was me on that issue and went with @mrahhal's solutions. That was more flexible and workaround for now as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  This issue was a bear for me.
I could not get `-enableRule:AppOffline` on my actual deployment command.  Nor could I get this to work in my pubxml file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(I'm using IIS v10)

This [Microsoft blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum/) indicates that either will work, but no dice for me!

Anyway, these 2 references helped me a lot:

1. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/50#issuecomment-268820798
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing

The real trick was in the second reference, the tile says "before Publishing". So you need to actually run `msdeploy.exe` separately before your main deploy.

Here is the PowerShell code I used:

```
# Deploy app_offline.htm
$IisApp = Get-IisAppName
$AppOfflineFilePath = "`"C:\path with spaces\app_offline.htm`""

Log-Begin "Deploy app_offline.htm"
& $MsDeployPath -verb:sync -source:contentPath=$AppOfflineFilePath -dest:contentPath=$IisApp/app_offline.htm,ComputerName=$ServerName,UserName=$UserName,Password=$Password,IncludeAcls="False"
Log-End "Deploy app_offline.htm" $LastExitCode

Write-Host "Sleeping for 4 seconds to give the app_offline.htm a chance to take effect."
Write-Host "If you get a locked DLL error, just try the deployment again!"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 4

# Within the ZIP file is a MS Web Deploy Package ZIP, a cmd (to run the deploy), and some other files.
$DeployCommandFilePath = Get-ChildItem $pwd *.deploy.cmd -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName.length -lt 260} | Select-Object -First 1 | Resolve-Path -Relative

Log-Begin "deploy.cmd"
& $DeployCommandFilePath /Y /M:$ServerName /U:$UserName /P:$Password
Log-End "deploy.cmd" $LastExitCode
```

Note that I added a short sleep to allow the app_offline.htm file a chance to take effect.  It is not immediate.

I have IIS set up to automatically delete the app_offline.htm file on a deploy, so I did not need this, but here is the code if you need it:

```
# Delete app_offline.htm
Log-Begin "Delete app_offline.htm"
& $MsDeployPath -verb:delete -dest:contentPath=$IisApp/app_offline.htm,ComputerName=$ServerName,UserName=$UserName,Password=$Password,IncludeAcls="False"
Log-End "Delete app_offline.htm" $LastExitCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing -retryInterval and/or -retryAttempts parameters:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/885
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx